# Unable to import SchemaDirectiveVisitor from apollo-server-express

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

```
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('apollo-server-express');

class ReplaceDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { replacement } = this.args;
    field.resolve = () => {
        return replacement
    }
}
}

module.exports = Object.freeze({ ReplaceDirective })
```

The Error I am getting is following
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [apollo-server/packages/apollo-server-express/src/index.ts](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/apollo-server-express/src/index.ts#L16-L22), that function is not exposed.

[SchemaDirectiveVisitor](https://www.graphql-tools.com/docs/legacy-schema-directives/) is a legacy function from `graphql-tools`.

[apollo-server-express@2.X.X (last v2.25.2)](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/apollo-server-express%402.25.2/packages/apollo-server-express/src/index.ts#L21) used [graphql-tools 4.0.8](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/blob/v4.0.8/src/index.ts#L6)
which still had that function.

You'll need to pin to a `v2` version of `apollo-server-express` to make use of that function.

Comment: Thanks Manny, but I'd like to stick with the latest version. How can I make custom directives in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

They got rid of the `SchemaDirectiveVisitor` and added two new functions to simplify: `mapSchema` and `getDirectives`.

Source:
https://www.the-guild.dev/blog/graphql-tools-v6
Then scroll to the following title.
Modify Schemas with Directives